# How to use the parameter of obj in androidplot

Tags: android

here is code from others, I wonder how to use the parameter of obj in Internal class?because I did not found where function was used:

```
    _ratePlot.setRangeValueFormat(new Format() {

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(Object obj, @NonNull StringBuffer toAppendTo,
                               @NonNull FieldPosition pos) {
        double val = ((Number) obj).doubleValue();
        double maxY = _ratePlot.getCalculatedMaxY().doubleValue();

        if (val == 0 || maxY < finalK) {
            return new DecimalFormat("0").format(val, toAppendTo, pos);
        } else if (maxY < finalK * finalK) {
            if (val < 10 * finalK)
                return new DecimalFormat("0.0 k").format(val / (1000), toAppendTo, pos);
            else
                return new DecimalFormat("0 k").format(val / (1000), toAppendTo, pos);
        } else {
            if (val < 10 * finalK * finalK)
                return new DecimalFormat("0.0 M").format(val / (finalK * finalK), toAppendTo, pos);
            else
                return new DecimalFormat("0 M").format(val / (finalK * finalK), toAppendTo, pos);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object parseObject(String source, @NonNull ParsePosition pos) {
        return null;
    }

});
```

I know the anonymous internal classes is defined here, but I can't found where it is used, what I mean is I don't understand how to know what value of variable val is. Here is the complete source code:
http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=i2p.android.base-master/app/src/main/java/net/i2p/android/router/stats/RateGraphFragment.java

Comment: what you're asking is unclear - could you elaborate?

Comment: I am sorry I am a non - native speakers. What I want to know is how to make sure what the value of variable val is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand what you're asking but I'll attempt to give some general information about what is happening in the code you posted.

Essentially, `_ratePlot.setRangeValueFormat(new Format()...)` is setting a custom `Format` to be used when rendering the range values along the edge the `XYPlot`.  Androidplot will call the format method on this anonymous inner class, passing in each range value as a `Number` in the `obj` parameter.  You have to cast it back to a `Number` inside this method because `Format` class is meant to be generic.  This is done in the first line of the method:

`double val = ((Number) obj).doubleValue();`

Once you have this value, it's up to you to decide how you want to format it. The rest of the method just does some formatting and returns the formatted result as a `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely. If I understand you correctly, the value of obj, or in other words, the value of Number, is depending on each range value, right?

Comment: Thank you so much!